Login API endpoint not present in swagger
I am trying to integrate with GeoNetwork 4.4 API to send records to /geonetwork/srv/api/records with a PUT request.
The result is always 403.
I tryed to use the geonetwork/srv/eng/xml.user.login to send the credentials with the X-XSRF-TOKEN and the JSESSIONID.
I can obtain the XSRF-TOKEN and the JSESSIONID but the login doest not return a token, return an HTML content.
I tryed api/users/login with the credentials but this return me a 400.
What is the correct way to authenticate with GeoNetwork API?

SOLVED : I solve the issue, the geonetwork in version 4.4 accepts basic authentication.
I passed the credentials in the header since the first GET to obtain xsrf token and the record was inserted.
The documentation about authentication is not so clear.
